# WebBrowser.DocumentText Not Updating

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am loading a web page into webbrowser control and after waiting for the document to load, I am reading in the .documenttext to retrieve various bits of data.

I then want to test if the data on the web page has changed (it's a dynamic update) and if so, I retrieve the updated data.

The problem is that .document.text is not updating, either after a dynamic update to the page or if I physically navigate within the browser control to another page.

When I loop through all elements using '.getelementsbytagname' I get the up to date web page data, but obviously want to avoid this if the data hasn't changed. So '.document' updates but '.documenttext' doesn't.

So the '.documenttext' doesn't get updated when the web page changes. Is there a way to force this update? Or a better/simpler way to check for a page update?

.refresh() does work, but I don't want to be reloading the document when it's already up to date.

```
Dim pp = Uni.wbUni.DocumentText

If pp = GlobalVariables.unistr Then
        Console.WriteLine("no change" & Now())
        Exit Sub
End If
Console.WriteLine("change" & Now())
GlobalVariables.unistr = Uni.wbUni.DocumentText
```

So from the above pp never actually updates

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim pp = Uni.wbUni.Document.Body.InnerText
```